# sorting through array of objects and setState cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop

I'm a noob to API and I'm trying to sort and store values fetched from the "Pexels" API. I'm making an image gallery as practice with React.js.

after making an array of objects I'm passing the values as a prop into the component. I use a forEach loop and within it, set the state... but this causes an infinite loop and I'm not sure why or what the work around is!

The App level code looks something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([
    {name:"James", age: 25, hairColor: "Lavender"},
    {name:"Jessie", age: 30, hairColor: "Maroon"},
    {name:"Meowth", age: 1, hairColor: "beige"}
  ]);

 return (   
  <div className="container">
    <Header 
      picUrl={headerInfo.imgUrl}
      posterName={headerInfo.name}
    />
    <NavBar />
    <Galary 
      testInfo={test}
    />      
  </div>
 );
}
```

component level:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const Gallary = ( {testInfo} ) => {

  const [name, setName] = useState([]);
  const dataSort = async ()=>{

    // Below is what causes the error!
    await testInfo.forEach( test =>{
       setName([...name, test.name]); // this causes  an infinite loop!
       console.log(test.name); // this iterates 3 times if not setting the state!
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="gallary-section">
        <h2>{ title }</h2>
        <div className="gallary">
            <GalImg
                profileImg={profileImg > 0 ? profileImg : profImg}
                name={name > 0 ? name : posterName}
                picUrl={picUrl > 0 ? picUrl : imgUrl}
                dlLink={dlLink > 0 ? dlLink : dlL}
            />
        </div>

        <Button bgColor="#7E4DD2" txtColor="#fff"  btnText="More" />
    </div>
  )
}

Gallary.defaultProps = {
  title: "Today's selection",
  profImg: "https://images.pexels.com/users/avatars/92810756/brian-lazo-240.jpeg?auto=compress&fit=crop&h=256&w=256",
  posterName: "Brian Lazo",
  imgUrl: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/9160984/pexels-photo-9160984.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260",
  dlL: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/9160984/download/?search_query=&tracking_id=so1xqtw586"
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for async/await there, and use `.map` to bring back a new array, then use that new array to set your state variable (which should be called `names` and `setNames`)

```
  useEffect(() => {
     let newNames = testInfo.map(test => test.name);
     setName(newNames)
},[testInfo]
```

OR set it up from the get-go, just be careful how you bring `testInfo` in to this component.

```
  const [name, setName] = useState(() => testInfo.map(test => test.name));
```

Comment: This works thanks! why was I running into infinite loops using for loops and forEach?

Comment: Probably because you were setting states in two different components at the “same time”. The forEach method mutates the original array directly, be careful with that as well.